# Getting Reports by Monthly Intervals

Tags: sql, sqlite

New to using SQLite. Needed some assistance with building a query.

Essentially, I need totals in monthly intervals grouped by category. Right now all 3 intervals display on the same column. I want each interval displayed as its own separate column. How would I go about that?

```
SELECT tickets.category AS 'Category', count(id) AS 'Interval'

FROM tickets 

WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',tickets.created_at) >= date('now','-30 days') 
    AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',tickets.created_at)<= date('now', '-7 days')

GROUP BY tickets.category

UNION ALL

SELECT tickets.category AS 'Category', count(id) 

FROM tickets 

WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',tickets.created_at) >= date('now','-60 days') 
    AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',tickets.created_at)<= date('now', '-31 days')

GROUP BY tickets.category

UNION ALL

SELECT tickets.category AS 'Category', count(id) 

FROM tickets 

WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',tickets.created_at) >= date('now','-90 days') 
    AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',tickets.created_at)<= date('now', '-61 days')

GROUP BY tickets.category

ORDER BY tickets.category DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called conditional aggregation. Use your `where` conditions in `count` to have them as separate columns.

```
SELECT category
,count(case when strftime('%Y-%m-%d',created_at) >= date('now','-30 days') 
       AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',created_at)<= date('now', '-7 days') then id end) as days_7_30
,count(case when strftime('%Y-%m-%d',created_at) >= date('now','-60 days') 
       AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',created_at)<= date('now', '-31 days') then id end) as days_31_60
,count(case when strftime('%Y-%m-%d',created_at) >= date('now','-90 days') 
       AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',created_at)<= date('now', '-61 days') then id end) as days_61_90
FROM tickets 
GROUP BY category
```

Comment: You sir, are a god.